# How do I include sender's name and not just the email address while emailing message from user input form

Tags: php, forms, email, input

I am trying to take inputs from a form on my website using a simple PHP script as given below:

```
<?php 
$toemail = 'xyz@anyemail.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
if(mail($toemail, 'Subject', $message, 'From: ' . $email)) {
    echo 'Your email was sent successfully.';
} else {
    echo 'There was a problem sending your email.';
}
?>
```

This worked perfectly. Well, almost. The email I receive does not include the sender's name. I would want to see a normal email response (with name of the sender in the name column of inbox and I should be able to see the email address of the sender when I open the mail.)

So I made a few changes after looking up some threads like this:

```
<?php 

$toemail = 'xyz@anyemail.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$email_from = $name.'<'.$email.'>';
$header = 'From: '.$email_from;


if(mail($toemail, 'Subject', $message, $header)) {
    echo 'Your email was sent successfully.';
} else {


echo 'There was a problem sending your email.';
    }

?>
```

Email response is still same. What do I need to change ?

Comment: Add a space before the <     : $email_from = $name.' <'.$email.'>';

Comment: $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your second body of code. Make sure you uploaded the right file(s) and have made the proper change in the form's action.

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP That didn't work.

Comment: I also followed this: [Link](http://htmldog.com/techniques/formtoemail/)
It still doesn't return sender's name as I would want.

Comment: You probably have a variable mismatch problem or something simple.  Can you run your code and add echo $header and then copy and paste what is displayed to your message so that we can see what exactly is in the header?

Comment: Nothing changes. Just expected response of "Your email was sent successfully". I also noticed something more. For the code given next, I don't ever get the name of sender even in the message body !
`$mailBody="Name: $name \nEmail: $email \n\n$message";
if(mail($toemail, "Response from website form", $mailBody, "From: $name <$email>")) {
 echo 'Your email was sent successfully.';
        echo $header; }` 
So the variable $name is goofing up somethwhere it seems...

Answer (score 1):

Try this format, note the spaces and the \r\n's, change your variables accordingly:

```
$email_headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$email_headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$email_headers .='From: YOURNAME <sender_email@yourdomain.com>' . "\r\n";
$email_headers .='Reply-To: reply_to_email@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n";

mail($recipient_address, $email_subject, $email_body, $email_headers);
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about variable names. In relation with the code I have given above, I am replacing YOURNAME with name and sender_email@yourdomain.com and reply_to_email@yourdomain.com with email. Doesn't work. I also tried $name and $email with and w/o single quotes. Doesn't work.

Comment: @user3518133 indeed, YOURNAME is any text representing the name, and the emails as you stated. When you say doesn't work - what do you mean? do you get anything in the server's log file? Or is it just not sending it. Do you have access to the server's PHP.ini file?

Comment: It seems the either the file doesn't exist or I don't have any access to it. I tried to search "php.ini" in the file manager provided by the host - cpanel. The search results are nil.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Quoted from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I have been through the link before. It confused me about the email address format to be used. Is that generic ? I don't think so !